# Recursive Funcion Calls in MIPS (with Stacks)

Tags: function, assembly, stack, mips

Can Someone explain the recursive function calls that gets stored in the stack and loads back? It's really confusing.

Thanks Beforhand.

For Example, I'm trying to understand the factorial function (recursive) from C to MIPS. But I can't.

Comment: In terms of the calling convention, a function that calls itself isn't different from a function that calls a different function.  As always, you need to store the return address somewhere, and any variables you want to read after the call need to be on the stack or in call-preserved registers (with their old values saved on the stack.)

Comment: Study the calling convention. See here: [In MIPS architecture, what is the difference between a register which is preserved and non preserved on calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76249075/471129).  Proper use of the calling convention is required whenever one function calls another.  As already stated, recursion is a [red-herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) — recursion adds no additional requirements to ordinary function calling on a system that uses a runtime call stack.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/76347719/471129

Answer (score 0):

Try not to worry about the recursion.

A factorial function looks something like this:

```
int fact ( int n ) {
    if ( n <= 1 ) return 1;
    return fact ( n-1 ) * n;   // or, return n * fact ( n-1 );
}
```

and the MIPS translation is:

```
fact:
    ble $a0, 1, EndIf1
    addiu $sp, $sp, -8       # allocate 8 bytes of stack space
    sw $a0, 4($sp)           # store n into the stack for later use in multiplication
    sw $ra, 0($sp)           # store return address for later use by return
    addi $a0, $a0, -1        # compute n-1 and pass to fact as parameter
    jal fact                 # fact function result (return value) is in $v0
    lw $a0, 4($sp)           # restore n from stack location, previously saved
    mul $v0, $v0, $a0        # perform multiplication sending result to $v0
    lw $ra, 0($sp)           # load return address
    addiu $sp, $sp, 8        # deallocate the 8 bytes previously allocated
    jr $ra                   # return to caller
EndIf1:
    li $v0, 1
    jr $ra
```

It is important to realize that in assembly language, a return address is the machine code value that refers to the location of the instruction one past caller's call site, which should be resumed when the function completes.  The return address is hidden in C code and other high level languages, whereas it is necessarily exposed in machine code/assembly language.

The `jr $ra` instruction transfers control to back to the caller by using the return address (while the return value is shared with the caller in the `$v0` register).  The `jal` instruction automatically sets the `$ra` register, which can be thought of as an additional parameter to the function (the place to return upon completion).  Since `jal` repurposes/overwrites `$ra`, if there is an important value in there (there is), it must be moved somewhere else that will survive the function call, so that it can be used later upon return.

The same is also true for `$a0` — we need to put `n-1` into `$a0` in order to make the call to `fact`, however, we need `n` after the call to fact, so also save `n` (from `$a0`) into the stack and restore after the call.

---

Ok, so here's a non-recursive version (that relies on the above `fact`):

```
int non_recursive_fact ( int n ) {
    if ( n <= 1 ) return 1;
    return fact ( n-1 ) * n;   // or, return n * fact ( n-1 );
}
```

and the assembly code for that:

```
non_recursive_fact:
    ble $a0, 1, EndIf1
    addiu $sp, $sp, -8
    sw $a0, 4($sp)
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $a0, $a0, -1
    jal fact
    lw $a0, 4($sp)
    mul $v0, $v0, $a0
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addiu $sp, $sp, 8
    jr $ra
EndIf1:
    li $v0, 1
    jr $ra
```

So, you see the code for each of these function can be identical, even though the former is recursive and the latter not.

---

The above are both written using the standard calling convention.  Non-standard calling convention optimizations are possible when the implementation of the code for both caller and callee are known, but not shown here since the point is to share the normal approach.  The advantage of the normal approach is that the caller and callee can exist in (the same or) different compilation units, and in order to make a call, all that is needed is to know the callee's function signature, not its internal machine code implementation.